# R: how to remove element form list / find its index?

Tags: r, list

I have (long) list. How to remove element if I don't know its index? Alternativly how to find element's index (then I can use list[-index]).
Example; I have list:

```
[[1]]  
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

[[2]]  
[1] "C" "D" "B" "C"

[[3]]  
[1] "B" "C" "D" "A"
```

and i want to remove

```
to.remove  
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: In general it is more convenient to work with named lists. You can easily remove an item from a named list if you know the name but not the index. Or if all your elements have length 4, why not use a data.frame instead, possibly with an extra `key` column? This would greatly facilitate subsequent data processing. Obviously whether this is feasible in your particular situation depends on how you ended up with that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for exact matches, you can use identical, in combination with sapply to look at each element in the list:

```
myList <- myList[!sapply(myList, identical, c("A", "B", "C", "D")]
```